# Tabela responsivo fica desformatada

Tags: html, css

Estou a criar a seguinte tabela responsivo, mas não está de acordo com o que pretendo:

CSS:

```
table {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font-family: arial;
  }

  .table {
    border-bottom: #999999 solid 1px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .table th,
  .table td {
    border-right: #999999 solid 1px;
    font-size: 8px;
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .table td:last-child {
     border-right: 0;
  }

  .table thead th {
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #005dab;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 8px;
  }

  .table tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
  .table tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
  }


/* Small Sizes */
@media (max-width: 767px) { 

  /* Responsive Table */
  .table-responsive {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .table-responsive thead,
  .table-responsive tbody,
  .table-responsive th,
  .table-responsive td,
  .table-responsive tr {
    display: block;
  }
  .table-responsive td,
  .table-responsive th {
    height: 35px;
  }

  .table-responsive thead {
    float: left;
  }

  .table-responsive tbody {
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .table-responsive tbody tr {
    display: inline-block;
  }


  .table td:last-child {
     border-right: #999999 solid 1px;
  }
}
```

Code:

```
$result_cursos = "SELECT * FROM raddb.ListagemPrduto WHERE Ativo = '1'";
$resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);

$tabela1 .= '<table class="table table-responsive">';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .='<thead>';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<th rowspan=2>Produtos</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th colspan=2>No Carro</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th colspan=2>Na Prateleira</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th colspan=2>Data na Emb.</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th rowspan=2>Observação</th>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Tem</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Não Tem</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Tem</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Não Tem</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Tem</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Não Tem</th>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</thead>'; 

$tabela1 .='<tbody>';

$y = 0;
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

$tabela1 .= '<div>';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" readonly="true" size="20" name= "Produto['.$y.']" class= "Produto" value="'.$rows_cursos['Descricao'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" class="r" name= "Sim['.$y.']" value="Ok" required></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" class="r" name= "Sim['.$y.']" value="Não Ok" required></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" class="p" name= "Stock['.$y.']" value="Ok"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" class="p" name= "Stock['.$y.']" value="Não Ok"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "DataP['.$y.']" value="Ok" '.$property.'></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "DataP['.$y.']" value="Não Ok" '.$property.'></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <textarea type="text" class= "Observacao" name="Observacao['.$y.']" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea></td>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 
$y++;
}

$tabela1 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela1 .= '</table>';

$tabela1 .= '</div>';

$tabela1 .= '</div>';

echo $tabela1;
```

Se visualizar em tela de computador, retorna assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se for na tela de telemóvel fica desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os cabeçalhos ficam de forma diferente, mesmo na vertical devia ficar com o formato igual ao do cabeçalho na horizontal

HTML renderizado:

```
<table class="table table-responsive" id="example"> 
    <thead>  
        <tr> 
            <th>Quarto</th>
            <th>Utente</th>
            <th>Inicio Tarefa</th>
            <th>Tarefa</th>
            <th>Fim Tarefa</th>
            <th>Colaborador</th>
            <th>Observações</th>            
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>  
            <?php  
        do{
    ?>  
            <td><?php echo $produto["Quarto"]; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $produto["nome"]; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $produto["IniciarTarefa"]; ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $produto["Descricao"]; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $produto["FimTarefa"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["Colaborador"]; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $produto["Observacao"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } while($produto = $result1->fetch_assoc()); ?>
        </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Cara e pq que vc está mexendo com o display da tabela. Pq vc esta mudando ele o os demais display de tr/td? A tabela era para funcionar perfeitamente, o que está "estragando" e vc mudando o display original para outro... Se puder edita a pergunta tb, e coloca uma tabela que já tenha side renderizada no HTML, com o código em HTML mesmo

Comment: @hugocsl  já editei a pergunta e adicionei tabela com o código html

Comment: Vc está usando Bootstrap? Se sim qual versão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te alertei no comentário, tabela é uma coisa que não se deve mudar os `display`, pois ela é uma estrutura complexa, com relação Intrínseco entra as partes `table>tr>td`

Removendo os display ela fica estável, mesmo em telas pequenas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código.

```css
table {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font-family: arial;
}

.table {
    border-bottom: #999999 solid 1px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.table th,
.table td {
    border-right: #999999 solid 1px;
    font-size: 8px;
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.table td:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}

.table thead th {
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #005dab;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 8px;
}

.table tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}


/* Small Sizes */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

    /* Responsive Table */
    .table-responsive {
        /* display: block; */
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .table-responsive thead,
    .table-responsive tbody,
    .table-responsive th,
    .table-responsive td,
    .table-responsive tr {
        /* display: block; */
    }

    .table-responsive td,
    .table-responsive th {
        height: 35px;
    }

    .table-responsive thead {
        /* float: left; */
    }

    .table-responsive tbody {
        width: auto;
        position: relative;
        overflow-x: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .table-responsive tbody tr {
        /* display: inline-block; */
    }


    .table td:last-child {
        border-right: #999999 solid 1px;
    }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-responsive" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Quarto</th>
            <th>Utente</th>
            <th>Inicio Tarefa</th>
            <th>Tarefa</th>
            <th>Fim Tarefa</th>
            <th>Colaborador</th>
            <th>Observações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <!-- <?php  
                do{
            ?> -->
            <td><?php echo $produto["Quarto"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["nome"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["IniciarTarefa"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["Descricao"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["FimTarefa"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["Colaborador"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["Observacao"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td><?php echo $produto["Quarto"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["nome"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["IniciarTarefa"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["Descricao"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["FimTarefa"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["Colaborador"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["Observacao"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td><?php echo $produto["Quarto"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["nome"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["IniciarTarefa"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["Descricao"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["FimTarefa"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["Colaborador"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["Observacao"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td><?php echo $produto["Quarto"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["nome"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["IniciarTarefa"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["Descricao"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["FimTarefa"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["Colaborador"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $produto["Observacao"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- <?php } while($produto = $result1->fetch_assoc()); ?> -->
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: estou com problema nesta pergunta que já foi respondida. Será que posso colocar uma dúvida no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98361/discussion-between-bruno-and-ivan-ferrer) uma vez que já fiz a pergunta e foi respondida?

Comment: @Bruno se for algo simples pergunta aqui que te respondo. Se for algo que vai precisar de mais código ai seria legal abrir uma nova pergunta e colocar seu código atual explicando o problema que encontrou etc, pois aqui não da para colocar código etc, então só daria para te responder em uma pergunta nova. Assim  agente não bagunça essa pergunta que já foi finalzada etc

Comment: o problema é que se abir uma pergunta nova irão colocar como duplicada, por isso perguntei se poderia falar no chat e expor o problema